# In order to get an Amazing Grace Winter Bash hat do I have to ask five questions on one site only

Tags: discussion

I know this is somewhat (no, read totally) pathetic, but I really want an Amazing Grace Winter Bash hat.  I need to ask four more questions on Christianity Stack to get my silver there, but can I also ask on other sites, such as Hermeneutics or Mi Yodyea?

Or do I have to concentrate on Christianity Stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's lot of silver badges, I don't think it matters where you get it or how you get it.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I didn't explain myself properly.  I only need to ask four more questions on Christianity Stack to get the silver badge, but what I want, what I really, really want, is the Amazing Grace Winter Bash HAT. So, do I have to stick to C.Stack or can I ask on the other sites in order to get the HAT?  (How sad is this?)

Comment: Yeah, you should stick to this site, asking questions about Christianity on the site sites is not likely to get you a silver badge and by extension the Amazing Grace hat.  :).  I'd gladly lend you mine.  (They should offer those as bounties next year)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340755/1765  Feature request for hat bounties

Comment: Appreciate the advice - and if hats can be offered up as a bounty for the next Winter Bash, that might be a very useful incentive. Now, all I have to do is come up with four (well-researched and intelligent) questions on Christianity Stack to get that hat!